# Is this footprint wrong or am I missing something?

Tags: esp32, footprint

I am looking for a suitable footprint for the ESP32-WROOM-32E module.

According to [the spec](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32e_esp32-wroom-32ue_datasheet_en.pdf) on page 26, the square pads in the center are 7.5mm removed from the border and are 0.9mm wide. However, in [this footprint that I found on SnapEDA](https://www.snapeda.com/parts/ESP32-WROOM-32E%20%2816MB%29/Espressif%20Systems/view-part/?ref=search&t=esp32-wroom-32E), the pads are 8mm away from the border and are more than 1mm wide.

This causes the whole grid to be offset significantly, as can be confirmed with the cad model in the 3D render:

[image]

Does nobody care because it doesn't matter, or am I missing something?

(I would be extra grateful if somebody could refer me to a footprint that does not have this shortcoming...)

Comment: Seems like there was a change, and that somebody indeed did notice it and care about it, a few weeks ago.
https://www.snapeda.com/questions/question/this-footprint-appears-to-be-outpdate-based-on-the/

Comment: Regarding the question where you can find a correct footprint, just draw one. It takes like 5 minutes to draw a simple footprint like this.

Comment: SnapEDA designs are submitted by users not manufacturers. Despite their "verification checker," footprints can still have problems. Use the **Issues** tab to report the mismatch. (Don't trust "free" resources.)